Why can I build .NET Framework 472 projects with solely .NET 8 installed?
the question is straight forward but I'm new to .NET and C#. I have a .csproj file that references as target framework 472
<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
even though solely .NET 8 is installed. This also works fine in my CI/CD pipelines.
I was just wondering and ask how does this work? For example changing the target framework to 481 failed my build. So can anyone explain this to me and if yes what is beeing executed? 472 or .NET 8? And what is recommended? Is it preferred to install .NET 8 even if it's not needed neccessarily?

"even though solely .NET 8 is installed." What is installed concretely the sdk or the runtime or both? You can't execute stuff of the old Net Framework with runtimes of the newer Net Core stuff (there was a mayor change after Net 4.8 but typically you can build stuff for old runtimes with newer sdks.

Ah my mistake. I installed .NET sdk 8 and following this command https://stackoverflow.com/a/78611196/24485185 Net Framework 4.8.0... is installed. I guess this explains why I weren't able to execute target framework 481?

Don't let the version number fool you the connection between version number and framework release version isn't that obvious. A few more details here. Besides in your question you state "failed my build" but in your comment now you say "weren't able to execute". Building and running are to different things done by different things (Sdk vs. Runtime). A current version Windows should have a current 4.8 pre installed that should be able to execute any app targeting a 4.x Framework.

Thanks a lot. Yes, mistake from my side. I meant build

.NET Framework 4.8 comes included with each Windows 10/11 installation, and is backwards compatible with 4.7.2 (and most other historic .net framework versions, for that matter).
So unless you explicitly removed it from the OS, your premise is off: you do also have .NET 4.8 installed.
You can check this using the following command line:
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\full" /v version

